# Deleting all records from sqllite android

Tags: java, android, sqlite

am trying to delete all records from the database and insert records which i get from remote db , every time the activity loads.

I am able to insert the data. but when i try to delete the all the records from the table i get the error.

my code

**Main Menu class**

```
public class mainmenu extends Activity {


    private ScheduleDAO mscheduleDAo;
    private VisitsDAO mvisitsDAO;
    private String storedkey;
    private String jsonfromapi;


    //schedule table variables
    private  String schedule_id = null;
    private  String schedule_name = null;
    private  String schedule_date= null;

    //visits table variables
    private String visit_id             = null;
    private String visit_schedule_id    = null;
    private String visit_name           = null;
    private String visit_time           = null;
    private String visit_place          = null;
    private String visit_address        = null;
    private String visit_location_lat   = null;
    private String visit_location_lng   = null;
    private String visit_status         = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_mainmenu);

        //Delete all records from visits and schedule tables
        // mscheduleDAo.deleteAllSchedule();
        mvisitsDAO.deleteAllVisits();

        //loading schedule list
        Button btn_sche = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_schedule);
        btn_sche.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(mainmenu.this, Schedule_Activity.class));
            }
        });

        //loading reset password
        Button reset = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_reset_password);
        reset.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(mainmenu.this, resetpassword.class));
            }
        });

        //loading google maps
        Button location = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_location);
        location.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(mainmenu.this, My_Location.class));
            }
        });


        try {
            String user_name = getdate_from_local();
            TextView user = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lbl_name);
            user.setText("Welcome : "+user_name+"\n");

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }



        // getting the list of schedules from the remote api
        get_schedule_list();


        try{

            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonfromapi); //Here reponse is the yours server response
            JSONObject result = jsonObject.getJSONObject("result");
            JSONArray sehedule = result.getJSONArray("sehedule");


            //save all schedules
            for(int i=0;i<sehedule.length();i++)
            {

                schedule_id = sehedule.getJSONObject(i).getString("schedule_id");
                schedule_date = sehedule.getJSONObject(i).getString("schedule_date");
                String[] parts = schedule_date.split(" ");
                String string1 = parts[0];
                schedule_date = string1;
                schedule_name = sehedule.getJSONObject(i).getString("schedule_name");

                insert_schedule();
                // Toast.makeText(this, schedule_date,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            //save all visits
            JSONArray visits = result.getJSONArray("visit");
            for(int i=0;i<visits.length();i++)
            {

                visit_id = visits.getJSONObject(i).getString("visit_id");
                visit_schedule_id = visits.getJSONObject(i).getString("schedule_id");
                visit_name = visits.getJSONObject(i).getString("visit_name");
                visit_time = visits.getJSONObject(i).getString("visit_time");
                visit_place = visits.getJSONObject(i).getString("visit_place");
                visit_address = visits.getJSONObject(i).getString("visit_address");
                visit_location_lat = visits.getJSONObject(i).getString("visit_location_lat");
                visit_location_lng = visits.getJSONObject(i).getString("visit_location_lng");
                visit_status = visits.getJSONObject(i).getString("visit_status");

                insert_visits();
            }


            //Save all items
            JSONArray items = result.getJSONArray("item");
            for(int i=0;i<items.length();i++)
            {
                String item_id = items.getJSONObject(i).getString("item_id");
                String visit_id = items.getJSONObject(i).getString("visit_id");
                String item_name = visits.getJSONObject(i).getString("item_name");
                String item_check_status ="1";
                String item_comment = "";
                String item_latitude = "";
                String item_longitude = "";
                String item_submit_time = "";
                String item_remote_status = "1";
            }

        }catch(Exception e)
        { }





    }




    private boolean insert_schedule(){
        mscheduleDAo =new ScheduleDAO(getApplicationContext());
        Schedule createdschedule = mscheduleDAo.createschedule(Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(schedule_id)),
                schedule_name,
                schedule_date);

        return true;
    }

    private boolean insert_visits(){
        mvisitsDAO = new VisitsDAO(getApplicationContext());
        Visits createvisits =mvisitsDAO.createvisits(Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(visit_id)),
                Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(visit_schedule_id)),
                visit_name, visit_time, visit_place, visit_address, visit_location_lat, visit_location_lng,
                Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(visit_status)));
        return true;
    }



    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private String readkeyfromfille() throws IOException {
        FileInputStream fis = openFileInput("myappkey.txt");
        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
        StringBuffer b = new StringBuffer();

        while(bis.available() !=0){
            char c = (char) bis.read();
            b.append(c);
        }

        String Key =b.toString();

        return Key;

    }

    public String getdate_from_local() throws IOException {

        String storedkey = readkeyfromfille();

        byte[] data = Base64.decode(storedkey, Base64.DEFAULT);
        String key_in_text = new String(data, "UTF-8");


        String[] parts = key_in_text.split(Pattern.quote("|"));
        String string1 = parts[0]; // 004
        String string2 = parts[1];

        return string1;
    }

    private void get_schedule_list(){
        try {
            jsonfromapi  = new MySchedules().execute(storedkey).get();

        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }






    //async task to get the schedule, visits, items details from remote database
    class MySchedules extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {


        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {


            // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://172.16.110.3/agent_tracking/index.php/api/rest/get-schedules/");

            try {
                // Add your data
                List<BasicNameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<>(1);
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("key", arg0[0]));
                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

                // Execute HTTP Post Request
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                String schedule_list = EntityUtils.toString(entity, "UTF-8");

                return schedule_list;

            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            }
            return null;
        }


        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String data) {
            if(data != null){
                jsonfromapi = data;  //you would get json data here
                //then do parse your json data
            }

        }


    }
    // end of async task

}
```

**VisitsDOA class**

```
public class VisitsDAO {

    public static final String TAG = "visitsDAO";


    // Database fields
    private SQLiteDatabase mDatabase;
    private DBHelper mDbHelper;
    private Context mContext;
    private String[] mAllColumns = {
            DBHelper.COLUMN_VISITS_ID,
            DBHelper.COLUMN_VISITS_SCHEDULE_ID,
            DBHelper.COLUMN_VISITS_NAME,
            DBHelper.COLUMN_VISITS_TIME,
            DBHelper.COLUMN_VISITS_PLACE,
            DBHelper.COLUMN_VISITS_ADDRESS,
            DBHelper.COLUMN_VISITS_LOCATION_LAT,
            DBHelper.COLUMN_VISITS_LOCATION_LNG,
            DBHelper.COLUMN_VISITS_STATUS  };

    public VisitsDAO(Context context) {
        this.mContext = context;
        mDbHelper = new DBHelper(context);
        // open the database
        try {
            open();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "SQLException on openning database " + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void open() throws SQLException {
        mDatabase = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    }

    public void close() {
        mDbHelper.close();
    }

    public Visits createvisits(int vid, int v_sid, String vname, String vtime, String vplace, String address, String vlat, String vlong, int vstatus) {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(DBHelper.COLUMN_VISITS_ID, vid);
        values.put(DBHelper.COLUMN_VISITS_SCHEDULE_ID, v_sid);
        values.put(DBHelper.COLUMN_VISITS_NAME, vname);
        values.put(DBHelper.COLUMN_VISITS_TIME, vtime);
        values.put(DBHelper.COLUMN_VISITS_PLACE, vplace);
        values.put(DBHelper.COLUMN_VISITS_ADDRESS, address);
        values.put(DBHelper.COLUMN_VISITS_LOCATION_LAT, vlat);
        values.put(DBHelper.COLUMN_VISITS_LOCATION_LNG, vlong);
        values.put(DBHelper.COLUMN_VISITS_STATUS, vstatus);
        long insertId = mDatabase
                .insert(DBHelper.TABLE_VISITS, null, values);
        Cursor cursor = mDatabase.query(DBHelper.TABLE_VISITS, mAllColumns,
                DBHelper.COLUMN_VISITS_ID + " = " + insertId, null, null,
                null, null);

        Visits newvisits = null;
        if (cursor != null&& cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            newvisits = cursorTovisits(cursor);

        }
        cursor.close();
        return newvisits;
    }



    public List<Visits> getAllvisits() {
        List<Visits> listVisits = new ArrayList<Visits>();

        Cursor cursor = mDatabase.query(DBHelper.TABLE_VISITS, mAllColumns,
                null, null, null, null, null);
        if (cursor != null) {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
                Visits visits = cursorTovisits(cursor);
                listVisits.add(visits);
                cursor.moveToNext();
            }

            // make sure to close the cursor
            cursor.close();
        }
        return listVisits;
    }

    public List<Visits> getAllvisitsforSchedule(int id) {
        List<Visits> listVisits = new ArrayList<Visits>();

        Cursor cursor = mDatabase.query(DBHelper.TABLE_VISITS, mAllColumns,
                DBHelper.COLUMN_VISITS_SCHEDULE_ID + " = ?",
                new String[]{String.valueOf(id)}, null, null, null);
        if (cursor != null) {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
                Visits visits = cursorTovisits(cursor);
                listVisits.add(visits);
                cursor.moveToNext();
            }

            // make sure to close the cursor

            cursor.close();
        }
        return listVisits;
    }

    public Visits getvisitById(int id) {
        Cursor cursor = mDatabase.query(DBHelper.TABLE_VISITS, mAllColumns,
                DBHelper.COLUMN_VISITS_ID + " = ?",
                new String[]{String.valueOf(id)}, null, null, null);

        if (cursor != null) {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
        }

        Visits visits = cursorTovisits(cursor);
        return visits;
    }

    protected Visits cursorTovisits(Cursor cursor) {
        Visits schedule = new Visits();

        schedule.setvId(cursor.getInt(0));
        schedule.setVschID(cursor.getInt(1));
        schedule.setVname(cursor.getString(2));
        schedule.setVtime(cursor.getString(3));
        schedule.setVplace(cursor.getString(4));
        schedule.setVaddress(cursor.getString(5));
        schedule.setVlat(cursor.getString(6));
        schedule.setVlong(cursor.getString(7));
        schedule.setVstatus(cursor.getInt(8));


        return schedule;

    }


    public void deleteVisits(Visits visits) {
        long id = visits.getvId();
        mDatabase.delete(DBHelper.TABLE_VISITS, DBHelper.COLUMN_VISITS_ID + " = " + id, null);
    }

    public void deleteAllVisits() {

        SQLiteDatabase db = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        db.delete(DBHelper.TABLE_VISITS, null, null);
    }


}
```

**dbhelper class**

```
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {


    public static final String TAG = "DBHelper";

    // columns of the schedule table
    public static final String TABLE_SCHEDULE= "schedule";
    public static final String COLUMN_SCHEDULE_ID = "schedule_id";
    public static final String COLUMN_SCHEDULE_NAME = "schedule_name";
    public static final String COLUMN_SCHEDULE_DATE = "schedule_date";

    // columns of the items table
    public static final String TABLE_ITEM= "items";
    public static final String COLUMN_ITEM_ID = "item_id";
    public static final String COLUMN_ITEM_VISIT_ID = "visit_id";
    public static final String COLUMN_ITEM_NAME = "item_name";
    public static final String COLUMN_ITEM_CHECK_STATUS= "item_check_status";
    public static final String COLUMN_ITEM_COMMENT = "item_comment";
    public static final String COLUMN_ITEM_LAT = "item_latitude";
    public static final String COLUMN_ITEM_LNG = "item_longitude";
    public static final String COLUMN_ITEM_SUB_TIME = "item_submit_time";
    public static final String COLUMN_ITEM_REMOTE_status = "item_remote_status";


    // columns of the employees table
    public static final String TABLE_VISITS = "visits";
    public static final String COLUMN_VISITS_ID = "visit_id";
    public static final String COLUMN_VISITS_SCHEDULE_ID = "schedule_id";
    public static final String COLUMN_VISITS_NAME = "visit_name";
    public static final String COLUMN_VISITS_TIME = "visit_time";
    public static final String COLUMN_VISITS_PLACE = "visit_place";
    public static final String COLUMN_VISITS_ADDRESS ="visit_address";
    public static final String COLUMN_VISITS_LOCATION_LAT = "visit_location_lat";
    public static final String COLUMN_VISITS_LOCATION_LNG = "visit_location_lng";
    public static final String COLUMN_VISITS_STATUS = "visit_status";

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "certisagent";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 7;

    // SQL statement of the visits table creation
    private static final String SQL_CREATE_TABLE_VISITS = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_VISITS + "("
            + COLUMN_VISITS_ID              + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, "
            + COLUMN_VISITS_SCHEDULE_ID     + " INTEGER, "
            + COLUMN_VISITS_NAME            + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
            + COLUMN_VISITS_TIME            + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
            + COLUMN_VISITS_PLACE           + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
            + COLUMN_VISITS_ADDRESS         + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
            + COLUMN_VISITS_LOCATION_LAT    + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
            + COLUMN_VISITS_LOCATION_LNG    + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
            + COLUMN_VISITS_STATUS          + " INTEGER "
            +");";


    // SQL statement of the schedule table creation
    private static final String SQL_CREATE_TABLE_SCHEDULE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_SCHEDULE + "("
            + COLUMN_SCHEDULE_ID        + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, "
            + COLUMN_SCHEDULE_NAME      + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
            + COLUMN_SCHEDULE_DATE      + " TEXT NOT NULL "
            +");";

    // SQL statement of the item table creation
    private static final String SQL_CREATE_TABLE_ITEMS = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_ITEM + "("
            + COLUMN_ITEM_ID            + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, "
            + COLUMN_ITEM_VISIT_ID      + " INTEGER, "
            + COLUMN_ITEM_NAME          + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
            + COLUMN_ITEM_CHECK_STATUS  + " INTEGER, "
            + COLUMN_ITEM_COMMENT       + " TEXT, "
            + COLUMN_ITEM_LAT           + " TEXT, "
            + COLUMN_ITEM_LNG           + " TEXT, "
            + COLUMN_ITEM_SUB_TIME      + " TEXT, "
            + COLUMN_ITEM_REMOTE_status + " INTEGER "
            +");";

    public DBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {
        database.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_TABLE_SCHEDULE);
        database.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_TABLE_VISITS);
        database.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_TABLE_ITEMS);


    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        Log.w(TAG,
                "Upgrading the database from version " + oldVersion + " to " + newVersion);
        // clear all data
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_SCHEDULE);
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_VISITS);
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_ITEM);

        // recreate the tables
        onCreate(db);
    }



}
```

**Error Stack**

```
 Process: lk.agent.certislanka.certisagenttracking, PID: 15681
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{lk.agent.certislanka.certisagenttracking/lk.agent.certislanka.certisagenttracking.mainmenu}: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2429)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2493)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:166)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1283)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5584)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at lk.agent.certislanka.certisagenttracking.mainmenu.onCreate(mainmenu.java:79)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5442)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2393)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2493)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:166)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1283)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5584)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at lk.agent.certislanka.certisagenttracking.mainmenu.onCreate(mainmenu.java:79)`

Comment: mvisitsDAO is null and you are a tool ... thats why there should be a filter on SO which would not accept questions with NullPointerException ...

Comment: This `mvisitsDAO.deleteAllVisits();` causes the error because `mvisitsDAO` is not instantiated

Answer (score 1):

You need to add 
`mvisitsDAO = new VisitsDAO(getApplicationContext());`
before you perform the delete in onCreate()